# pl/sql procedure that check 1 month from sysdate

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need a procedure that will check is the date_of_sell is more that 30 days from sysdate, then in_stock will change to "not in stock" and online_stock will change to "1"

```
create table items (
    item_no number not null,
    item_name varchar2(30) not null,
    description_item varchar2(100) null,
    date_of_sell date,
    in_stock varchar2(20) not null,
    online_stock number(1) default 0 not null,
    check (in_stock in ('In stock', 'not in stock', 'closed'));
```

```
create or replace procedure update_stock (item_no in number)


    as
    begin
update items 
    set in_stock = 'not in stock',  online_stock = 1    
    where date_of_sell <= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE());
end update_stock;
/
```

Comment: "*I need a procedure*" - SO isn't a place to write the whole code for you. Show us your attempt.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry for that, I edit the question with procedure. anyway I got the error :PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DATEADD": invalid identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function like `DATEADD` in Oracle. You can simply add a positive or negative integer to a `date` to add or subtract days.Use `SYSDATE` instead of `getdate()`. You may do a `TRUNC` on `SYSDATE` to ignore time component.

Also, for arguments, do not use the column names as it is. You may use something like `p_item_no`.Did you intend to use it in your procedure in the where clause? I don't see it being used.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_stock (
     p_item_no IN NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE items 
      SET in_stock      = 'not in stock', 
         online_stock = 1    
      WHERE                             --p_item_no = ?
        date_of_sell <= SYSDATE - 30;   --TRUNC(SYSDATE) if you want to ignore time.
END update_stock;
/
```

Comment: Oh no, it will be in parameter, when I will call the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Adding some value on top of the previous answer, If you exactly want 1 month (not 30 days) before some date then you can use the `ADD_MONTHS` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_stock (
     p_item_no IN NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE items 
      SET in_stock      = 'not in stock', 
         online_stock = 1    
      WHERE                                         --p_item_no = ?
        date_of_sell <= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 1);   --TRUNC(SYSDATE) if you want to ignore time.
END update_stock;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: why it's not working with add_days? it's ok with add_months, but it suppose to be dynamic number of days, so using add_months it's not a best way..

Comment: what if I will date_of_sell = sysdate - 30; ?

Comment: I gave answer considering your question title, which is describing 1 month. Not every month has 30 days.